What is the most performant way of modelling a many-to-many-manies relationship?
I have a data model that looks like this:
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE bar (
  id PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE baz (
  id PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE users_permissions (
  user_id INT UNIQUE REFERENCES users (id),
  foo_ids ARRAY ( INT UNIQUE REFERENCES foo (id) ),
  bar_ids ARRAY ( INT UNIQUE REFERENCES bar (id) ),
  baz_ids ARRAY ( INT UNIQUE REFERENCES baz (id) )
);

To my mind, there are three ways I could model this in Postgres:

define users_permissions as a table (with one row per user_id and one column per array of foreign keys);

would sorting the arrays improve the speed of updates? or does the query planner not take that into account?
this definitely feels like it fails some level of normalisation


split the users_permissions relation above into several linking tables (users_foos, users_bars and users_bazzes) and then either:

query these tables directly as needed using several array_aggs and a GROUP BY user_id;
do the above but with a defined VIEW;
query a MATERIALIZED VIEW of the above; or
define several user_has_permission_for_{foo,bar,baz}(user_id) functions and just use the minimum number that I need each time.



As far as I can tell, each has major pros and cons:

defining a table would allow me to use a UNIQUE constraint on user_id, but Postgres doesn't support foreign key referencing for array elements so there'd be no constraints there (I'd have to check for duplicates, invalid references etc. in the application logic);
splitting into several linking tables gives me the advantage of defining foreign key constraints, and in terms of interacting with the data in aggregate:

querying the tables would result in a lot of very complex queries, as well as the performance hit of making several complicated queries across multiple tables frequently, but would be quick to update and would guarantee the data is always up-to-date;
a VIEW would have same-or-worse performance as the table, but would simplify queries; whilst
a MATERIALIZED VIEW would be very performant, but would need to be refreshed (with CONCURRENT) on every change of permissions

if the feature is implemented in Postgres in the future, these updates could be made more performant via incremental refreshes





So am I right in thinking that option 2.3 is the best option provided I expect permission updates to be infrequent (and proportionally much much less so than reads)?
Am I also right in thinking that the view refresh overhead would be constant for both single-user updates and bulk updates for any number of users (i.e. the materialised view refresh operation is O(1)), as both cases would only require a single REFRESH at the end of the underlying table updates (as part of a single transaction)?

Update 2024-07-25: I set up a mock DB and ran some tests, it seems like table and materialised view performance is about equal for SELECTs and regular views are about twice as slow:

However this is with the table and views populated using the following simplified query:
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    coalesce ( array_agg( uf.foo_id ) FILTER ( WHERE uf.foo_id IS NOT NULL ) ), 
    coalesce ( array_agg( ub.bar_id ) FILTER ( WHERE ub.bar_id IS NOT NULL ) )
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_foos AS uf ON uf.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN users_bars AS ub ON ub.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id;

I expect that as that query becomes more complex and involves more joins, the performance of the table would degrade much faster than the materialised view.
I also tested insert speeds (note the logarithmic y-axis):

Sorting the arrays appears to worsen performance, although I'm not sure if there's some way of signifying to the query planner that they are sorted that I'm missing (or writing a custom method as in this article). I also had to use this workaround for the fact that I can't use sort() on a BIGINT[].

Don't use arrays. Approach 2 is better. I also expect the queries to perform better, even if they may appear more complicated.
